# Zeros of an analytic function.

Tags: real-analysis

Are the zeros of a non-constant real analytic function $f$ from a finite dim, real vector space $V$ to the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ which takes values in $[0,1]$ always a countable set?

Update:

Is it possible for there to be an analytic function which is not constant in any of its variables (i.e. dimensions of $V$) which has uncountably many zeros?

Comment: Can someone elaborate what we mean by a real analytic function in the case that $V \not \subseteq \mathbb R$?

Comment: @Stefan Of course if the domain is "a vector space" this is not so clear. But if the domain is, say, $\Bbb R^n$ it just means that $f$ is given by a power series in a neighborhood of each point.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ok, that's what I thought. As I don't often deal with these aspects of analysis, I wasn't sure if there is a standard generalization that I'm unaware of.

Comment: See edit for answer to revised question...

Comment: The generic case (in some sense) is that the zeros of a differentiable function $f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}$, where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, form an $n-1$-dimensional set.

Comment: @Benjamin Daniel's comment really hits the nail on the head.  What examples gave you the impression that the set of zeros would be countable?  This strikes me as extremely rare, so it doesn't seem like you put much thought into the question.  Yet you keep modifying it to avoid counterexamples, as if you have some reason to believe it's true in some context.  Please provide that context if you have it?

Comment: Is it true for a single variable i.e. $V=\mathbb{R}$? I thought it was, that was the motivation.

Comment: Yes, it's true for $V=\Bbb R$. (And yes, it seems clear to me that that's why one might think it was true in general.)

Comment: See yet one more edit

Comment: @Benjamin Yes it's true for $V=\mathbb R$.  My point is that it isn't true for any higher dimension, which is the purpose of the generalization.  Is there a motivation for adding restrictions like $[0,1]$ and non-constant in each variable?  Normally one adds such restrictions to separate counterexamples from an actual example, which is why I asked if you had one.  If the only examples are dimension 1, then the obvious separation is the number of dimensions in $V$.  But if you have an example in dim $2$ that would add greatly to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For instance, define $f:\Bbb R^2\to[0,1]$ by $f(x,y) = x^2/(1+x^4)$.

For the revised question, "not constant in any of its variables"", change that to $f(x,y)=(x+y)^2/(1+(x+y)^4)$.

---

Just so you get your money's worth: Yes, it's true for $V=\Bbb R$. Two ways to see this: (i) in that case $f$ is the restriction to $\Bbb R$ of a function holomorphic in some neighborhood of $\Bbb R$ in the plane.

(ii) Say $x_n\to x$ and $f(x_n)=0$ for every $n$. It follows that $f^{(k)}(x)=0$ for every $k$...

Comment: Not sure why you didn't go for $f(x,y) = x$ instead :D . Since the answer has been deleted, I cannot comment on Benjamanins comment, but $f(x,y) = x-y$ shows that such a function does not have to be constant in one variable.

Comment: @Stefan Because he asked about $f:V\to[0,1]$. Details...

Comment: Oh, I missed that part of the question. Thanks.

Comment: In this case, $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{2+2x^4} - \frac{y^2}{2+2y^4}$ answers Benjamins question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x, y) = \sin^2(x)$.